# Running a python script to configure mpir for windows, visual studio 2017 and c++17

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2017, c++17, mpir

I'm extremely new to python, I've just got it set up on Visual Studio 2017CE version 15.6.6 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Home Premium. I went through a couple of walk through tutorials and can verify that at the least Python is installed and working.

I'm trying to follow instructions from the MPIR documentations on building the needed libraries for (c/c++) to run in Visual Studio. I have the tools needed: I have Python, VYASM, and MPIR, MPFR and MPFRC++. I have all the newest versions of the libraries from the websites directly (no third party). These are default distributions.

While reading through the documentation for MPIR; It mentions that I should run the Python Script (mpir_config.py) where N is the version of the visual studio that you will be building the libraries (static-dll) - (debug-release) versions. It states that I should run the Python Script first, and it also states that if available to choose a custom build for specific platforms-architects according to your cpu.

Here is the list that is generated from running Python script (module) in the Python Shell without any arguments.

```
 1. gc                              
 2. p3                       (win32)
 3. p3_p3mmx                 (win32)
 4. p4                       (win32)
 5. p4_mmx                   (win32)
 6. p4_sse2                  (win32)
 7. p6                       (win32)
 8. p6_mmx                   (win32)
 9. p6_p3mmx                 (win32)
10. pentium4                 (win32)
11. pentium4_mmx             (win32)
12. pentium4_sse2            (win32)
13. atom                       (x64)
14. bobcat                     (x64)
15. bulldozer                  (x64)
16. bulldozer_piledriver       (x64)
17. core2                      (x64)
18. core2_penryn               (x64)
19. haswell                    (x64)
20. haswell_avx                (x64)
21. k8                         (x64)
22. k8_k10                     (x64)
23. k8_k10_k102                (x64)
24. nehalem                    (x64)
25. nehalem_westmere           (x64)
26. netburst                   (x64)
27. sandybridge                (x64)
28. sandybridge_ivybridge      (x64)
29. skylake                    (x64)
30. skylake_avx                (x64)
Space separated list of builds (1..30, 0 to exit)?
```

My system is a Intel DP45SG motherboard with chip set P45 running a QuadCore Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650, 3.0Ghz (9x333).

The Alias or code names are Intel Skyburg for the mother board. Intel Eaglelake for the chipset, and Yorkfield for the processor.

I don't know what selection I should choose if any... That's the first half of the problem. The other half is if I am to choose one being that it is appropriate; how do I run the mpir_config.py file to set this? Does it accept an argument as you call it? Or do you run it in the shell then give it a value? Or would the actual code within the script have to be changed? I'm a Python noobie... you can call me (worm) I haven't reached the status of a snake yet. Being that I'm new to Python and I have no idea what to do next.

Now as for setting up projects in visual studio to actually build out the (c/c++) libraries from their solutions, setting the configurations and even setting environment variables is not a problem for me. Any and all help would be appreciative.

*All of this hassle because boost's multi precision library uses GMP which does not really support windows...*

Comment: I just love it when people down vote and never give a reply why, at least with a comment of criticism one can make changes to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Intel Core 2 Quad Q9650 is a Yorkfield core from the Penryn family,
18. core2_penryn               (x64)
should be fine.

Comment: Yeah Intel's website didn't tell me anything since it is a long over due discontinued model. At least the mother board is. The processor also has the name Yorkfield. I found it out on Wiki!

Answer (score 1):

And for the second part of your question, mpir_config.py will generate 2 projects in the mpir-3.0.0\build.vc15 solution directory : one for the dynamic lib, and one for the static lib.
Just open mpir.sln and build the desired one.